# Build query to get chat conversation messages in sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Lets say i have the following model schema described as below to add some chat functionality between 2 users in my sails app. For instance if i have user A sending a message to user B, then user B will reply back to user A which will always create 2 conversations between both users. So my question is how can i query both conversations to get messages from A and B. I tried something like this but maybe theres a simple logic.

```
// User Model

attributes: {
  username: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    unique: true,   
  },
  conversations_sender: {
    collection: conversation,
    via: 'sender'
  },
  conversations_recipient: {
    collection: conversation,
    via: 'recipient'
  }
}

// Conversation model

attributes: {
  sender: {
    model: user
  },
  recipient: {
    model: user
  },
  messages: {
    collection: 'message',
    via: 'conversation'
  }
}

// Message model

attributes: {
  text: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  conversation: {
    model: 'conversation'
  },    
}

// Conversation Controller

get: function(req, res) {
  var params = {
    or : [
      { 
        sender: req.param('sender'),
        recipient: req.param('recipient')
      },
      { 
        sender: req.param('recipient'),
        recipient: req.param('sender')
      }
    ]
  }

  Conversation.find(params) ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink your schema a bit, see this link that has a good database design for your needs:

http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html

You should be able then to fetch all the messages with the 2 user ids like this:

```
 Conversation.findAll({sender: ..., receiver: ...})
```

Also you will need a timestamp for the messages, in the future you'll want to sort them somehow and also make the nice 'Read yesterday' feature

Comment: createdAt and updatedAt fields are automatically created by Sails on each model.

Comment: If you use the generators, but in his code there wasn't any created and updated fields